# Invertibility of linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra

In class the professor said that if linear function FG is invertible, then both F and G are invertible if they are of finite dimension. Is it still true for infinite dimension?

Comment: what are $F$, $G$?

Comment: Linear functions

Comment: and what is the dimension of a linear function ?

Comment: and FG means, the product of this functions?

Comment: Yes, I think the prof means that if FG is not of finite dimension, then the statement doesnt hold. I'm not quite sure.

Comment: $F$ and $G$ are maps of the same dimension? I mean you can have a $m$ by $n$ matrix times a $n$ by $m$ matrix giving a $m$ by $m$ matrix which is invertible, but each of the two matrices are not square and hence not invertible. Do you mean $F$ and $G$ are both square matrix?

Comment: I think if you are talking about matrices then they are finite dimensional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the space $\ell^2$ and denote $L:\ell^2\rightarrow \ell^2$ to be the left shift operator, i.e if $x= (x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ then $Lx = (x_2, x_3, \ldots)$, and $R:\ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ is the right shift operator. Then we see $LR = I$ but $L$ is not invertible.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much!